# How to connect to WiFi access point using WPS with a Samsung Galaxy Star Pro GT-S7262

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-star

I have Samsung Galaxy Star Pro GT-S7262. I want to connect it to a WiFi router using WPS pin of this router - but this mobile does not have this option.

So what can I do? Is there a way to connect?

Comment: According to http://www.howto-connect.com/galaxy-star-pro-gt-s7262-potential-problems-and-solutions/ your phone does support WPS... do a search on the link I've given for "WPS" and you'll find some useful instructions... You need to go to your wifi settings and find the advanced settings page :)

Comment: In wifi settings /  advanced settings there is NO wps option .. Is there an app or anything else to do ?!